# Mod_rewrite редирект всех запросов на index.php кроме ajax

Tags: ajax, mod_rewrite

mod_rewrite редирект всех запросов на index.php кроме ajax

Answer (score 3):

С точки зрения сервера ajax запросы не отличаются от обычных. Поэтому вариант все скрипты для ajax назвать определённым образом, скажем, поместить в папку `/actions/ajax/` и прописать правила mod_rewrite исходя из этого.